# VXLAN on top of EIGRP/I-BGP

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, vxlan

for labbing purposes, I have two NX-9000 that's connected to each other via EIGRP. Trying to have one as Spine switch and the other as Leaf switch. 
No redundancy/HA needed at the moment

Could you critic this configuration as why no peers are coming up?
Thanks in advance

#### Spine

```
Spine# show run

!Command: show running-config
!Time: Thu Nov  9 19:15:00 2017

version 7.0(3)I5(2)
power redundancy-mode combined force

hostname Spine
vdc Spine id 1
  limit-resource vlan minimum 16 maximum 4094
  limit-resource vrf minimum 2 maximum 4096
  limit-resource port-channel minimum 0 maximum 511
  limit-resource u4route-mem minimum 248 maximum 248
  limit-resource u6route-mem minimum 96 maximum 96
  limit-resource m4route-mem minimum 58 maximum 58
  limit-resource m6route-mem minimum 8 maximum 8

feature bash-shell
nv overlay evpn
feature ospf
feature bgp
feature pim
feature eigrp
feature interface-vlan
feature vn-segment-vlan-based
feature nv overlay
feature telemetry

username admin password 5 31$23LGhgRp$tT540F2l04NrG5hPZBQFNW/4wC8HSJVCzrAJX1uiKn6  role network-admin
ip domain-lookup
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
copp profile strict
snmp-server user admin network-admin auth md5 0xc62028034fec86b2b09020359b79db22 priv 0xc62028034fec86b2b09020359b79db22 lo
calizedkey
rmon event 1 log trap public description FATAL(1) owner PMON@FATAL
rmon event 2 log trap public description CRITICAL(2) owner PMON@CRITICAL
rmon event 3 log trap public description ERROR(3) owner PMON@ERROR
rmon event 4 log trap public description WARNING(4) owner PMON@WARNING
rmon event 5 log trap public description INFORMATION(5) owner PMON@INFO
ntp server ntp.qa.lab.com use-vrf management
ntp source-interface  mgmt0

vlan 1,10,20,30,40,100,200,870-872,880-882,890-893
ip pim rp-address 100.1.1.1 group-list 225.0.0.0/8
ip pim rp-address 192.168.0.7 group-list 224.0.0.0/4
ip pim rp-address 192.168.0.8 group-list 224.0.0.0/4
ip pim rp-address 192.168.0.111 group-list 224.0.0.0/4
ip pim bsr rp-candidate loopback1 group-list 225.0.0.0/8
ip pim ssm range 232.0.0.0/8
ip pim anycast-rp 100.1.1.1 10.1.1.1
ip pim anycast-rp 100.1.1.1 20.1.1.1
ip pim sg-expiry-timer infinity

vrf context management
  ip name-server 8.8.8.8
  ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.7.0.1
vrf context managment
  ip name-server 8.8.8.8

interface Vlan1
  no shutdown

interface Vlan10
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.1.13/24

interface Vlan20
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.2.13/24

interface Vlan30
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.3.13/24

interface Vlan40
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.4.13/24

interface Vlan100
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.100.13/24

interface Vlan200
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.200.13/24

interface Vlan882
  no shutdown
  ip address 192.168.201.13/30
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode

interface Vlan890
  no shutdown
  ip address 192.168.201.2/30
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode

interface Ethernet1/1
  switchport access vlan 890

interface Ethernet1/2
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/3
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/4
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/5
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/6
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/7
  switchport access vlan 100

interface Ethernet1/43
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/44
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/45
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/46
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/47
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/48
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 10

interface Ethernet1/49
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/50
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/51
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/52
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/53
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/54
  switchport access vlan 200

interface mgmt0
  vrf member management
  ip address 10.7.0.13/24

interface loopback0
  ip address 192.168.0.7/32
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode

interface loopback1
  ip address 192.168.0.17/32
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode

interface loopback2
  ip address 192.168.0.111/32
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode
line console
line vty
  session-limit 16
boot nxos bootflash:/nxos.7.0.3.I5.2.bin 
router eigrp 2018
router bgp 65000
  router-id 192.168.0.107
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  address-family l2vpn evpn
    retain route-target all
  template peer LEAF-PEER
    remote-as 65000
    update-source loopback0
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      send-community
      send-community extended
      route-reflector-client
    address-family l2vpn evpn
      send-community
      send-community extended
      route-reflector-client
  neighbor 192.168.0.8
    inherit peer LEAF-PEER
  neighbor 192.168.0.108
    inherit peer LEAF-PEER
  neighbor 192.168.201.14
    inherit peer LEAF-PEER


Spine#
```

#### Leaf

```
Leaf# show run

!Command: show running-config
!Time: Thu Nov  9 19:15:33 2017

version 7.0(3)I5(2)
power redundancy-mode combined force

hostname Leaf
vdc Leaf id 1
  limit-resource vlan minimum 16 maximum 4094
  limit-resource vrf minimum 2 maximum 4096
  limit-resource port-channel minimum 0 maximum 511
  limit-resource u4route-mem minimum 248 maximum 248
  limit-resource u6route-mem minimum 96 maximum 96
  limit-resource m4route-mem minimum 58 maximum 58
  limit-resource m6route-mem minimum 8 maximum 8

feature telnet
feature nxapi
feature bash-shell
feature scp-server
nv overlay evpn
feature ospf
feature bgp
feature pim
feature eigrp
feature interface-vlan
feature vn-segment-vlan-based
feature lldp
feature nv overlay
feature telemetry

username admin password 5 31$jEYE28hU$VhSgCZulJyyt/DAGWEQ2OXUL.VVTm5WF.xqnkxAsc02  role network-admin
ip domain-lookup
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
copp profile strict
snmp-server user admin network-admin auth md5 0x455bca72819925c42bb26ea92859c53d priv 0x455bca72819925c42bb26ea92859c53d lo
calizedkey
rmon event 1 log trap public description FATAL(1) owner PMON@FATAL
rmon event 2 log trap public description CRITICAL(2) owner PMON@CRITICAL
rmon event 3 log trap public description ERROR(3) owner PMON@ERROR
rmon event 4 log trap public description WARNING(4) owner PMON@WARNING
rmon event 5 log trap public description INFORMATION(5) owner PMON@INFO
ntp server ntp.qa.lab.com use-vrf management
ntp source-interface  mgmt0

vlan 1-400,602,861-862,870-872,880-883,999
fabric forwarding anycast-gateway-mac 0000.2222.3333
ip pim rp-address 100.1.1.1 group-list 225.0.0.0/8
ip pim rp-address 192.168.0.7 group-list 224.0.0.0/4
ip pim rp-address 192.168.0.8 group-list 224.0.0.0/4
ip pim bsr rp-candidate loopback1 group-list 225.0.0.0/8
ip pim ssm range 232.0.0.0/8
ip pim anycast-rp 100.1.1.1 10.1.1.1
ip pim anycast-rp 100.1.1.1 20.1.1.1
ip pim sg-expiry-timer infinity
vlan 140
  name L2-VNI-140-Tenant1
  vn-segment 50140
vlan 141
  name L2-VNI-141-Tenant1
  vn-segment 50141
vlan 999
  vn-segment 50999

spanning-tree vlan 1,140-141,999 priority 4096
vrf context Tenant-1
  vni 50999
  rd auto
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    route-target both auto
    route-target both auto evpn
vrf context management
  ip name-server 8.8.8.8
  ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.7.0.1
vrf context managment
  ip name-server 8.8.8.8


interface Vlan1

interface Vlan10
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.1.11/24

interface Vlan20
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.2.11/24

interface Vlan30
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.3.11/24

interface Vlan40
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.4.11/24

interface Vlan100
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.100.11/24

interface Vlan140
  no shutdown
  vrf member Tenant-1
  no ip redirects
  ip address 172.21.140.1/24
  fabric forwarding mode anycast-gateway

interface Vlan141
  no shutdown
  vrf member Tenant-1
  no ip redirects
  ip address 172.21.141.1/24
  fabric forwarding mode anycast-gateway

interface Vlan200
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.200.11/24

interface Vlan861
  no shutdown
  ip address 192.168.203.1/24
  ip router eigrp 2018

interface Vlan862
  no shutdown
  ip address 192.168.200.33/30
  ip router eigrp 2018

interface Vlan872

interface Vlan882
  no shutdown
  ip address 192.168.201.14/30
  ip router eigrp 2018

interface Vlan883
  no shutdown
  ip address 192.168.200.17/30
  ip router eigrp 2018

interface Vlan999
  no shutdown
  vrf member Tenant-1
  ip forward

interface nve1
  no shutdown
  source-interface loopback1
  host-reachability protocol bgp
  member vni 50140
    mcast-group 239.0.0.140
  member vni 50141
    mcast-group 239.0.0.141
  member vni 50999 associate-vrf

interface Ethernet1/1
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/2
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/3
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/45
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/46
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/47
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/48
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/49
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/50

interface Ethernet1/51

interface Ethernet1/52

interface Ethernet1/53

interface Ethernet1/54

interface mgmt0
  vrf member management
  ip address 10.7.0.11/24

interface loopback0
  ip address 192.168.0.8/32
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode

interface loopback1
  ip address 192.168.0.18/32
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode

interface loopback2
  ip address 192.168.0.222/32
  ip router eigrp 2018
  ip pim sparse-mode
line console
line vty
  session-limit 16
boot nxos bootflash:/nxos.7.0.3.I5.2.bin 
router eigrp 2018
router bgp 65000
  router-id 192.168.0.108
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  address-family l2vpn evpn
    retain route-target all
  template peer LEAF-PEER
    remote-as 65000
    update-source loopback0
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      send-community
      send-community extended
      route-reflector-client
  neighbor 192.168.0.6
    remote-as 65000
    address-family l2vpn evpn
      send-community
      send-community extended
  neighbor 192.168.0.7
    inherit peer LEAF-PEER
    remote-as 65000
    address-family l2vpn evpn
      send-community
      send-community extended
  neighbor 192.168.0.13
    inherit peer LEAF-PEER
  neighbor 192.168.0.107
    inherit peer LEAF-PEER
  neighbor 192.168.201.13
evpn
  vni 50140 l2
    rd auto
    route-target import auto
    route-target export auto
  vni 50141 l2
    rd auto
    route-target import auto
    route-target export auto


Leaf#
```

#### Log/Status

```
Spine# show ip bgp summ
BGP summary information for VRF default, address family IPv4 Unicast
BGP router identifier 192.168.0.107, local AS number 65000
BGP table version is 35, IPv4 Unicast config peers 3, capable peers 1
0 network entries and 0 paths using 0 bytes of memory
BGP attribute entries [0/0], BGP AS path entries [0/0]
BGP community entries [0/0], BGP clusterlist entries [0/0]

Neighbor        V    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
192.168.0.8     4 65000     166     171       35    0    0 00:00:15 0  


Leaf# sho ip bgp summ
BGP summary information for VRF default, address family IPv4 Unicast
BGP router identifier 192.168.0.108, local AS number 65000
BGP table version is 34, IPv4 Unicast config peers 3, capable peers 1
0 network entries and 0 paths using 0 bytes of memory
BGP attribute entries [0/0], BGP AS path entries [0/0]
BGP community entries [0/0], BGP clusterlist entries [0/0]

Neighbor        V    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
192.168.0.7     4 65000     165     166       34    0    0 00:00:33 0       



Leaf# sho nve peer
Leaf# 

Leaf# show vxlan inter
Interface       Vlan    VPL Ifindex     LTL             HW VP
=========       ====    ===========     ===             =====
Eth1/49         140     0x5308c7d0      0x1801          2050
Eth1/49         141     0x5308d7d0      0x1802          2051
Eth1/49         999     0x533e77d0      0x1803          2052

No port-channels configured (0x0)
Leaf# show nve vni
Codes: CP - Control Plane        DP - Data Plane          
       UC - Unconfigured         SA - Suppress ARP

Interface VNI      Multicast-group   State Mode Type [BD/VRF]      Flags
--------- -------- ----------------- ----- ---- ------------------ -----
nve1      50140    239.0.0.140       Up    CP   L2 [140]                
nve1      50141    239.0.0.141       Up    CP   L2 [141]                
nve1      50999    n/a               Up    CP   L3 [Tenant-1]           

Leaf#
```

### Update

```
Leaf# do sho ip bgp summ
BGP summary information for VRF default, address family IPv4 Unicast
BGP router identifier 192.168.0.107, local AS number 65000
BGP table version is 106, IPv4 Unicast config peers 3, capable peers 1
6 network entries and 10 paths using 1808 bytes of memory
BGP attribute entries [2/312], BGP AS path entries [0/0]
BGP community entries [0/0], BGP clusterlist entries [0/0]

Neighbor        V    AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
192.168.0.8     4 65000     512     525      106    0    0 00:00:11 6
```

### network

```
router bgp 65000
  router-id 192.168.0.107
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    network 192.168.0.7/32
    network 192.168.0.17/32
    network 192.168.201.0/30
    network 192.168.201.12/30
```

### BGP

```
Spine# show ip bgp
BGP routing table information for VRF default, address family IPv4 Unicast
BGP table version is 183, local router ID is 192.168.0.107
Status: s-suppressed, x-deleted, S-stale, d-dampened, h-history, *-valid, >-best
Path type: i-internal, e-external, c-confed, l-local, a-aggregate, r-redist, I-injected
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete, | - multipath, & - backup

   Network            Next Hop            Metric     LocPrf     Weight Path
* i192.168.0.7/32     192.168.0.8                       100          0 i
*>l                   0.0.0.0                           100      32768 i
*>i192.168.0.8/32     192.168.0.8                       100          0 i
* i192.168.0.17/32    192.168.0.8                       100          0 i
*>l                   0.0.0.0                           100      32768 i
*>i192.168.0.18/32    192.168.0.8                       100          0 i
* i192.168.201.0/30   192.168.0.8                       100          0 i
*>l                   0.0.0.0                           100      32768 i
* i192.168.201.12/30  192.168.0.8                       100          0 i
*>l                   0.0.0.0                           100      32768 i

Spine#
```

#### show ip route

```
Leaf# show ip route
IP Route Table for VRF "default"
'*' denotes best ucast next-hop
'**' denotes best mcast next-hop
'[x/y]' denotes [preference/metric]
'%<string>' in via output denotes VRF <string>

10.0.1.0/24, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.1.11, Vlan10, [0/0], 1w2d, direct
10.0.1.11/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.1.11, Vlan10, [0/0], 1w2d, local
10.0.2.0/24, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.2.11, Vlan20, [0/0], 1w2d, direct
10.0.2.11/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.2.11, Vlan20, [0/0], 1w2d, local
10.0.3.0/24, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.3.11, Vlan30, [0/0], 1w2d, direct
10.0.3.11/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.3.11, Vlan30, [0/0], 1w2d, local
10.0.4.0/24, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.4.11, Vlan40, [0/0], 1w2d, direct
10.0.4.11/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.4.11, Vlan40, [0/0], 1w2d, local
10.0.100.0/24, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.100.11, Vlan100, [0/0], 1w2d, direct
10.0.100.11/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.100.11, Vlan100, [0/0], 1w2d, local
10.0.200.0/24, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.200.11, Vlan200, [0/0], 1w2d, direct
10.0.200.11/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached
    *via 10.0.200.11, Vlan200, [0/0], 1w2d, local
10.2.200.12/30, ubest/mbest: 2/0
    *via 192.168.200.18, Vlan883, [90/4352], 03:19:40, eigrp-2018, internal
    *via 192.168.200.34, Vlan862, [90/4352], 03:19:39, eigrp-2018, internal
10.2.200.16/30, ubest/mbest: 2/0
    *via 192.168.200.18, Vlan883, [90/4608], 03:19:40, eigrp-2018, internal
    *via 192.168.200.34, Vlan862, [90/4608], 03:19:39, eigrp-2018, internal
30.1.1.1/32, ubest/mbest: 2/0
    *via 192.168.200.18, Vlan883, [90/132352], 03:19:40, eigrp-2018, internal
    *via 192.168.200.34, Vlan862, [90/132352], 03:19:39, eigrp-2018, internal
40.1.1.1/32, ubest/mbest: 2/0
    *via 192.168.200.18, Vlan883, [90/132608], 03:19:40, eigrp-2018, internal
    *via 192.168.200.34, Vlan862, [90/132608], 03:19:39, eigrp-2018, internal
192.168.0.7/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0
    *via 192.168.201.13, Vlan882, [90/130816], 03:19:39, eigrp-2018, internal
192.168.0.8/32, ubest/mbest: 2/0, attached
    *via 192.168.0.8, Lo0, [0/0], 03:19:53, local
    *via 192.168.0.8, Lo0, [0/0], 03:19:53, direct
192.168.0.17/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0
    *via 192.168.201.13, Vlan882, [90/130816], 03:19:39, eigrp-2018, internal
192.168.0.18/32, ubest/mbest: 2/0, attached
    *via 192.168.0.18, Lo1, [0/0], 03:19:43, local
    *via 192.168.0.18, Lo1, [0/0], 03:19:43, direct
192.168.0.111/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0
    *via 192.168.201.13, Vlan882, [90/130816], 03:03:53, eigrp-2018, internal
192.168.0.222/32, ubest/mbest: 2/0, attached
    *via 192.168.0.222, Lo2, [0/0], 03:03:23, local
    *via 192.168.0.222, Lo2, [0/0], 03:03:23, direct
Leaf#
```

Comment: BGP has no routes?

Comment: not showing up on "sho ip route" but entire configs are put to show bgp peering attempt (but they are able to ping each other's loopback)

Comment: You do not even see `192.168.0.8/32` and `192.168.0.18/32` in `show ip route`? Can you please update your question with the output of "show ip route"?

Comment: updated with "sho ip route" FYI.. there's eigrp backbone

Comment: Can you please post the output of "show ip route" on Spine device as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - a few things worth noting here, in no particular order:

1. "sho ip bgp sum" isn't going to show you numbers for EVPN routes.  You could, in fact, completely omit the `address-family ipv4` stanzas if you wanted.  Seeing an established / working session with no messages is actually expected for your setup.  If you *want* to see some routes show up then create a network statement pushing some routes from the global network (i.e. the underlay).
2. The correct equivalent to `show ip bgp sum` would actually be `sh bgp l2vpn evpn summary` - which, if things are working, will show EVPN routes received from various peers.  Other variants of this command tree will also show you info about EVPN: `sh bgp l2vpn evpn` will show you the raw EVPN routes, for example (including L2/L3 info, VNI, etc, etc).
3. The routes received (and used) will show up not under `sh ip route` but rather under `show ip route vrf [vrfname|all]`.
4. It's best practice to actually push the subnet routes within the vrf's on the leaves.  So, for example, under the VRF's stanza in the BGP section (ideally using some kind of tag as a discriminator): add `redistribute connected route-map <foo>` where the `<foo>` route-map would simply match some tag value that would be added to the interface IP address on the SVI.  The point here is that you want to have the leaves initiate the subnet's /24 (for example).  If you don't then you'll *only* see the individual host routes that the HMM creates on the leaf.  This is especially painful for situations where traffic is being sent to hosts that haven't been seen/announced yet, as they'll be sent an unreachable message.
5. Do **not** use SVI's for carrying VXLAN traffic between leaf and spine.  It can- and *might*- work on particular hardware but it's a far, far better design to just set up the transit interfaces as routed (`no switchport`) and let things work that way.  Put another way, there should be no SVI's on the spines (for leaf connectivity) and any SVI's on the leaf should only be host-facing.
6. The "route-reflector client" statement *ONLY* goes on the spines (..where I'm assuming you'd want to run your RR, otherwise we should be seeing more peers on the leaf).
7. It's not breaking anything yet, but set up jumbo frames on the transit interfaces between leaves and spines.  If you want to run jumbos to end clients my recommendation would be to stick to 9000 for such SVI's while using 9216 for inter-switch links.
8. The fact that you're seeing anything under the `show nve peer` suggests that things are actually working better than you may realize.  These won't generally form unless BGP is operating.
9. EIGRP actually isn't officially supported by Cisco for EVPN configurations.  It works fine and there's zero reason why it shouldn't, but hasn't been explicitly validated (IS-IS and OSPF have been).
10. Is there some typo with the router-id's?  The sample leaf calls out a BGP router ID of 107 and 108 for leaf and spine respectively but those IP's don't appear as loopbacks in your configs (17 and 18 do, though).  Also, specify a router-id in your global EIGRP process.

Comment: thank you for your time writing this. but if you look again, "show nve peer" shows blank, but "show vxlan inter" shows stuff

Comment: OK.  The rest applies - look at the “show BGP” commands.

Comment: thanks for your time. i'm going to rebuild the topology and do this time with OSPF and "no switchport"